# Как изменить ip томката?

Tags: tomcat

Как изменить ip томката с localhost на "вручную введенный IP-адресс"

Comment: Что значит "изменить ip"? Изменить адрес машины? Изменить адрес, на котором томкат ждёт соединений?

Comment: @Sheridan мне просто нужно чтобы вместо localhost сервер работал на другом IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Насколько я понял](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623/1597497), в файле `tomcat/conf/server.xml` нужно найти тег Connector и отредактировать его в нужную сторону:

```xml
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    address="127.0.0.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
  />
```

Вам нужно поменять 127.0.0.1 на нужный адрес